# how to get PIDs spawn from a particular folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, pid

I have a program that in distributed mode creates a folder and spawns a bunch of sub processes. Is there any way to find all PIDs that were executed from this folder? Sort of opposite of 
$ pwdx pid

where you give a path name and you get a bunch of pids.

thanks

Comment: more superuser.com question -> you can find answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/363169/ps-how-can-i-recursively-get-all-child-process-for-a-given-pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reporting all processes which [absolute path](https://superuser.com/questions/103309/how-can-i-know-the-absolute-path-of-a-running-process) is inside '/usr/bin/' may be done like this:

```
ls -l /proc/*/exe 2>/dev/null | grep /usr/bin/ | sed 's@.*/proc/@@;s@/exe.*@@;' | grep -v "self"
```

Reporting all processes which working directory (working directory can be changed by a simple `cd`) is inside `/tmp/a` could be done like this:

```
ps axo pid | xargs -n1 pwdx 2>/dev/null | grep ': /tmp/a' | sed 's/:.*//'
```

Comment: Thanks! The second one is exactly what I want !

Comment: Remember to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). ; )